# How does isDisplayed() in protractor/webDriver work?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

All of a sudden in our testing for our organization, the use of `isDisplayed()` just stopped being consistent.

Now it could be something that our Devs changed. But my question is what is `isDisplayed()` doing under the hood? What does it look for exactly? How does it work?

Answer (score 2):

isDisplayed looks for the if the element is displyed in the browser screen. **The display property tests whether any part of the element drawn is inside viewport. This is determined by the algorithm.**  In selenium it implemented as following.

```
/**
   * Test whether this element is currently displayed.
   *
   * @return {!Promise<boolean>} A promise that will be
   *     resolved with whether this element is currently visible on the page.
   */
  isDisplayed() {
    return this.execute_(
        new command.Command(command.Name.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED));
  }
```

IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED is itself an ENUM defined in the webdriver.CommandName.

The command is passed (IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED) uses the JsonWireProtocol to get the displayed property using the following get method:

```
session/:sessionId/element/:id/displayed
GET /session/:sessionId/element/:id/displayed
Determine if an element is currently displayed.
URL Parameters:
:sessionId - ID of the session to route the command to.
:id - ID of the element to route the command to.
Returns:
{boolean} Whether the element is displayed.
Potential Errors:
NoSuchWindow - If the currently selected window has been closed.
StaleElementReference - If the element referenced by :id is no longer attached to the page's DOM.
```

From the W3C and JsonWireProtocol which is implemented by selenium. I have quoted it down. [https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#element-displayedness]

> "The approach recommended to implementors to ascertain an element's
>   visibility was originally developed by the Selenium project, and is
>   based on crude approximations about an element's nature and
>   relationship in the tree. An element is in general to be considered
>   visible if any part of it is drawn on the canvas within the boundaries
>   of the viewport.
>
> The element displayed algorithm is a boolean state where true
>   signifies that the element is displayed and false signifies that the
>   element is not displayed. To compute the state on element, invoke the
>   Call(bot.dom.isShown, null, element). If doing so does not produce an
>   error, return the return value from this function call. Otherwise
>   return an error with error code unknown error."

Simple words as I learned:

1. If the element is not present in the DOM tree, call `isDisplayed()` will report `NoSuchElementException`, this is why protractor has `isPresent()` API.
2. If the element size is zero, selenium will treat it as not dispalyed even
   set `dispaly: block` CSS on the element
3. element or its parent/ancestors' CSS value of display set to `none` (`display: none`), the element is not displayed.

Comment: That helps a bit, I guess I am just wondering what that algorithm looks for? Is it purely the CSS value display?

Comment: Here you can see more about the  Call(bot.dom.isShown, null, element) which is called as mentioned in text above. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/e09e28f016c9f53196cf68d6f71991c5af4a35d4/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L437